# Ejecutar test URLs en background | PHP

Tags: php, test, procesos-en-segundo-plano, background

Necesito comprobar que todas las URLs que tengo guardadas en una BD (mysql) funcionen y no devuelvan Error 404 al hacer click en ellas en los diferentes sitios donde aparecen en mi web. Una vez comprobadas se mostrarán por pantalla en la web todas aquellas que no funcionan y el lugar de la web donde se encuentran para poder eliminarlas.

Para ello tengo un script en PHP que cuando el usuario en la web le da a lanzar test se tira como 10 minutos para poder devolverme el resultado de todas las URLs que no funcionan, por lo que necesitaría poder ejecutar este proceso en segundo plano y ir guardando los resultados en alguna otra tabla de la BD.

Ahora mismo lo que hago es obtener las URL de la BD (de 4 tablas diferentes) y hacer un foreach para cada tipo (adjunto un trozo):

```
    $urlsUniversitat = $universitiesModel->getURLUniversities();
    $urlsFooter = $adminManagmentModel->getURLSubsection();
    $urlsAssignaturesExternes = $acordsModel->getURLsAcords();
    $urlAssignaturesUAB = $assignaturesModel->getURLAssignatures();

    $failedURLS = array();

    //Modificamos el time limit para que no pete
    set_time_limit(200000);

    $options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true);


    //URLS Unis
    foreach ($urlsUniversitat as $urlUni){
        $urlPrincipal = $urlUni['urlUniversitat'];
        $handleURLPrincipal = curl_init($urlPrincipal);
        curl_setopt_array($handleURLPrincipal, $options);
        $responsePrincipal = curl_exec($handleURLPrincipal);
        $urlHeaderPrincipal = curl_getinfo($handleURLPrincipal, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        $urlIntercanvi = $urlUni['urlIntercanvis'];
        $handleURLIntercanvi = curl_init($urlIntercanvi);
        curl_setopt_array($handleURLIntercanvi, $options);
        $responseIntercanvi = curl_exec($handleURLIntercanvi);
        $urlHeaderIntercanvi = curl_getinfo($handleURLIntercanvi, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($urlHeaderPrincipal == 404 || $urlHeaderPrincipal == 0){
            array_push($failedURLS, array('modul' => "URL Universitat",'redirect' => $urlUni['idUniversitat'], 'url' => $urlPrincipal));
        }

        if ($urlHeaderIntercanvi == 404 || $urlHeaderIntercanvi == 0){
            array_push($failedURLS, array('modul' => "URL Intercanvi", 'redirect' => $urlUni['idUniversitat'], 'url' => $urlIntercanvi));
        }

        curl_close($handleURLPrincipal);
        curl_close($handleURLIntercanvi);
    }

    //URLS Footer
    foreach ($urlsFooter as $url){

        $urlPrincipal = $url['urlApartat'];
        $handler = curl_init($urlPrincipal);
        curl_setopt_array($handler, $options);
        $response = curl_exec($handler);
        $urlHeader = curl_getinfo($handler, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($urlHeader == 404 || $urlHeader == 0){
            array_push($failedURLS, array('modul' => "Footer", 'redirect' => $url['titolApartat'], 'url' => $urlPrincipal));
        }

        curl_close($handler);
    }
```

La idea sería que al guardar en la BD el resultado del proceso que se ejecute en background, pueda luego mostrar por pantalla la hora y día en la que se ha hecho el test y los resultados, así como poder volver a ejecutarlo.

Soy bastante novato en todo el tema web y PHP y no se me ocurre como podría ejecutar esto en segundo plano o con que herramienta hacerlo, me podríais dar algún consejo?

Comment: No entiendo mucho qué sentido tiene hacer esto ¿? Si tienes problemas con ciertas URL puedes implementar redirecciones vía `.htaccess` para esas URLs problemáticas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es porque en la web hay bastantes URLS que redirijen a paginas webs de universiades del mundo y el objetivo es facilitar al administrador de la web aquellas URLs que ya no existen porque se han modificado, entonces la idea es testear estas URLS y mostrar por pantalla aquellas que ya no funciona para que sepa donde se encuentran de la web y poderlas borrar

Comment: Entiendo. Pero ¿no es más simple capturar los errores 404 por ejemplo e ir creando un registro de las URLs que los provocan? Así sabrás a ciencia cierta cuáles son las URLs que no funcionan.

Comment: @A.Cedano No acabo de entender a que te refieres. Justamente lo que hago ahora es comprobar si estas dan error 404, el problema es que al haber tantas urls tarda mucho en devolverme el resultado, de ahí que quisiera hacerlo en segundo plano.

Comment: O sea, para normalizar la situación, simplemente sería tener un código que, cuando ocurra un error 404 capture esa URL, consulte si la misma existe en la tabla y si no existe la inserte. Luego el administrador verificará qué URLs hay en esa tabla e irá normalizándolas y borrándolas o marcándolas como resueltas. No entiendo por qué hay que consultar de forma masiva las URLs en la BD con el consiguiente impacto que esto tiene para el entorno. Lo que creo es que no estás afrontando la solución del problema de la forma más simple y más óptima.

Comment: En vez de gatillar el proceso con un request a tu sitio, ejecutarlo mediante un cron por línea de comando.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que al hacer una petición tarda mucho en dar el 404, pon un timeout mas pequeño al curl: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS,100)`, pero poner una entrada en el cron para que te lo haga solo, y simplemente revisas el resultado

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo lo que me comentas, el problema es que es lo que me piden para una parte del Trabajo de Fin de Carrera y pues tengo que hacerlo así.

Comment: @ffflabs no soy muy experto con el tema de cron por bash, sabes de algun ejemplo?

Comment: @Pepote Pensaba que eso se controlaba con el set_time_limit(200000); El problema que si este time limit lo pongo más bajo peta, pruebo a poner lo que me dices. En cuanto al cron, sabes de algun ejemplo? Soy bastante novato y sé solamente lo que nos han enseñado en la uni y las cosas que aprendo a base de googlear. Muchas gracias a los 3 por contestar!

Comment: set_time_limit es el tiempo que puede ejecutar el php.
El timeout que te he dicho es el tiempo que el curl tarda en decidir si responde una web o no.

Comment: @Pepote me olvidé de comentarlo pero lo solucioné con lo que me dijiste. Lo digo por si lo quieres poner como respuesta al post. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @maber03 respuesta creada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el proceso sea más rápido puedes bajar el timeout del curl, así recibirás antes el error 404.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS,100)
```

Ejecutar el proceso en el batch cada día puede ser una buena opción.

Ejemplo sencillo para ejecutar cada día las 12 de la noche usando cron:

```
0 0 * * * /path/script.php
```